# windows service failing while sending report as PDF with System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: reporting-services, windows-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to send SSRS report as PDF from a windows service. This works fine for me on my local machine and staging setup, but I get below error on production environment. This seems to be some permission issue to me but I am not able to pinpoint the exact issue. Below is error looged in windows service logs:

```
<log4j:event logger="MyProjectNamespace.Logger" timestamp="1352927717254" level="ERROR" thread="377">  
    <log4j:message>The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.  </log4j:message>
    <log4j:properties>  
        <log4j:data name="log4net:UserName" value="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" />  
        <log4j:data name="log4jmachinename" value="<My server machine name>" />  
        <log4j:data name="log4japp" value="<My windows service exe name>" />  
        <log4j:data name="log4net:HostName" value="<My host name>" />  
    </log4j:properties>  
    <log4j:throwable>
```

System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

```
From stacktrace, line which is producing error is below:
    Rse2005.ExecutionInfo ei = rsExec.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);

here "rsExec" is object of type "Rse2005.ReportExecutionService", historyId is NULL
```

My code to create report PDF is below:

```
private static void RenderReport(string reportFormat, string reportPath, string parameterLanguage, Rse2005.ParameterValue[] rptParameters, string outputFilePath)
        {
            string historyID = null;
            string deviceInfo = null;
            string encoding = String.Empty;
            string mimeType = String.Empty;
            string extension = String.Empty;
            Rse2005.Warning[] warnings = null;
            string[] streamIDs = null;

            Rse2005.ReportExecutionService rsExec = new Rse2005.ReportExecutionService();
            rsExec.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            Rse2005.ExecutionInfo ei = rsExec.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);
            rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(rptParameters, parameterLanguage);
            Byte[] results = rsExec.Render(reportFormat, deviceInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

            File.WriteAllBytes(outputFilePath, results);
        }
```

this method gets reportPath like "folderName/reportName".

I am also displaying the same report using reportViewer control from a webApp (on same server) and there it works perfectly.
My report server, windows service and webApp are all on same server

I tried to give user "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" permissions in report site settings and changing reportPath to full path with server name (like http:///reportserver/folderName/ReportName), but these didn't helped. Please suggest what else I can check and fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NT Authority\System` is a local system account. It cannot access resources on another machine, and sometimes local resources are secured to keep this account from access. So if you are giving this account permissions on a different machine (such as the SQL server), then it's not really the same account as the one running your service.

Try running your service with a domain user's credentials. Set that user up with the appropriate permissions in SSRS.